# CronJobService - what bean scope should I use?

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduler

I'm creating an infrastructure for cron jobs in my spring project.
All @scheduled annotations exists inside my services beans.

I created a generic CronJobService that should create the history of my cron execution and persistence of that history each time a cron job executes.

So, I've autowired this cronJobService to all services that use the @scheduled annotation and they call him and do stuff..

My question is: 
What scope should that cronService be? on the one hand it cant be singleton since lots of crons can call it simultaneously and i don't want to manage the sync in it.
On the other hand, i don't want it to live forever and have many beans that will infest my spring container.

thanks!